# There exist infinitely many positive integers such that...

Tags: real-numbers, pigeonhole-principle

For any $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_k$, there exist infinitely many positive integers $n$ such that

$$||na_i||$ = $\min{(\{na_i\},1-\{na_i\})}\leq n^{-1/k} \text{ for }1\leq i\leq k$$.

Here, $\{x\}$ denotes the fractional part of $x$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.